# facebook page api

Tags: java, facebook

I develop website for client. Now I need to integrate feature, which allow user to post text on his page. The users are companies & assumption is they will have their page. I am kind of confuse with facebook app and facebook page.

Can somebody please explain me steps. Also any java library which I can use for that. And do I need to create app for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to create an app. [RestFB](http://restfb.com/) might be a good library to start with.